How to upgrade zlib in Dockerfile
I have a Dockerfile which installs node:14.19.3-alpine which has a vulnerability in zlib. To remediate it I need to upgrade zlib.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------- base ---

FROM node:14.19.3-alpine as base

COPY . .
RUN apk add zip unzip
RUN npm install
RUN lerna bootstrap
RUN npm cache verify
RUN npm run build

How do I upgrade the zlib version
I tried to add the npm install zlib==1.2.12-r2 but that didnt work

You seem to be confused about which package manager to use. Try apk add zlib==1.2.12-r2 but I suspect you need to apk update before that will work.
